# Get-ChildItem: Illegal characters in path

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to login to multiple servers and then get list of files from those servers.

Below is my script:

```psh
$ServerName=Get-content "D:\HOMEWARE\BLRMorningCheck\Jerry\servername.txt"
foreach ($server in $ServerName)
{
  $server_host=echo $server | %{$data = $_.split(";"); Write-Output "$($data[0])"}
  $Targetfolder=echo $server | %{$data = $_.split(";"); Write-Output "$($data[1])"}

  $Extension =@("*.log","*.txt*")

  $Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse 

  echo $Files
}
```

When I run I debug mode I see that it really doesnt pick the files.

Error:

```
Get-ChildItem : Illegal characters in path.
At D:\HOMEWARE\BLRMorningCheck\Jerry\test.ps1:14 char:23
+ $Files = Get-Childitem <<<<  $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (D:\HOMEWARE\BLR...ck\Jerry\Check":String) [Get-ChildItem], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'D:\HOMEWARE\BLRMorningCheck\Jerry\"\srvparrtfh01\d$\HOMEWARE\BLRMorningCheck\Jerry\Check"' because it does not exist.
At D:\HOMEWARE\BLRMorningCheck\Jerry\test.ps1:14 char:23
+ $Files = Get-Childitem <<<<  $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\HOMEWARE\BLR...ck\Jerry\Check":String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Note: If I run it manually, example

```psh
$Files = Get-Childitem \\servername\d$\HOMEWARE\BLRMorningCheck\Jerry\Check -Include "*.log","*.txt*" -Recurse
```

I get the output.

Comment: You need to solve this: `Cannot find path 'D:\HOMEWARE\BLRMorningCheck\Jerry\"\srvparrtfh01\d$\HOMEWARE\BLRMorningCheck\Jerry\Check"' because it does not exist.` Have you echoed out the `$TargetFolder` variable? It looks like it's incorrect from this error message

Comment: Hi acro444,

Yes I'm able to echo the Targetfolder

echo $server_host $Targetfolder

SRVPAREMSH04
"\\SRVPAREMSH04\d$\Homeware\LogManagement\Jerry_sam"

Comment: You need to trim quotes from `$Targetfolder`.

Comment: @PetSerAl,

Could you please give the syntax, I'm quite new to powershell. Thanks

Comment: `$Targetfolder=$Targetfolder.Trim('"')`

Comment: @PetSerAl, Thanks a lot it worked.

Could you please help me with this as well?
I'm picking the extensions that I need from another file. But I'm not sure how to use it with @ symbol while passing.

$Extension=echo $server | %{$data = $_.split(";"); Write-Output "$($data[2])"}

$Extension =@($Extension)

$Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse

Comment: You better to update your question and provide sample of input data. It hard to say something without seeing it.

Comment: Ok thanks. Let me ask a separate question. Appreciate your response. Thanks once again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @arco444 and @PetSerAl mentioned in the comments: your path string has leading/trailing double quotes, which are invalid characters in a path. You need to remove them to make the path work as intended:

```psh
$Files = Get-Childitem ($TargetFolder -replace '^"|"$') -Include $Extension -Recurse
```

Of course, since your input file seems to be a some sort of CSV, you could use `Import-Csv` instead of reading the file with `Get-Content` and manually splitting the fields. That would already take care of the double quotes on file import.

```psh
$filename  = 'D:\HOMEWARE\BLRMorningCheck\Jerry\servername.txt'
$extension = '*.log', '*.txt*'

Import-Csv $filename -Delimiter ';' -Header 'ComputerName', 'TargetFolder' | % {
  Get-Childitem $_.TargetFolder -Include $extension -Recurse 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an absolute nightmare, get-childitem cannot except a string variable if there are multiple paths.

> Get-ChildItem -Path "\server1\c$\temp", "\server1\d$\temp" -File
> -recurse # works

> $path = '"\server1\c$\temp", "\server1\d$\temp"'; Get-ChildItem -Path "\server1\c$\temp", "\server1\d$\temp" -File
> -recurse # fails with cannot find path

> $path = "'"\server1\c$\temp", "\server1\d$\temp'""; Get-ChildItem -Path "\server1\c$\temp", "\server1\d$\temp" -File
> -recurse # fails with illegal character message (the tick)

Any string that has multiple paths fails, however an array with += as shown below will work.

```
$servers = @("server1", "server2");
$partialPaths = @("\c$\temp\", "\d$\temp\");
foreach ($server in $servers)
    {
        $paths = @();
        foreach ($partialPath in $partialPaths)
        {
            $paths += "\\" + $server + $partialPath;
        }
    }   
Get-ChildItem -Path $paths -File -recurse;
```